# scope and class method with the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I'm trying to use the Mailboxer Gem and I ran into problems when creating a conversations controller.

Now when I call current_user.mailbox.inbox I get the following:

```
You tried to define a scope named "new" on the model "Mailboxer::Conversation", but Active Record already defined a class method with the same name.
```

I have removed my conversations controller and actions but this is still showing.

Is it possible that a Gem Scope and method are clashing? perhaps the rails g controller added files else where?

Below is the model where the scope is defined. (This is from the Mailboxer Gem)

```
    class Mailboxer::Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :mailboxer_conversations

  attr_accessible :subject if Mailboxer.protected_attributes?

  has_many :opt_outs, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Mailboxer::Conversation::OptOut"
  has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => "Mailboxer::Message"
  has_many :receipts, :through => :messages,  :class_name => "Mailboxer::Receipt"

  validates :subject, :presence => true,
                      :length => { :maximum => Mailboxer.subject_max_length }

  before_validation :clean

  scope :participant, lambda {|participant|
    where('mailboxer_notifications.type'=> Mailboxer::Message.name).
    order("mailboxer_conversations.updated_at DESC").
    joins(:receipts).merge(Mailboxer::Receipt.recipient(participant)).uniq
  }
  scope :inbox, lambda {|participant|
    participant(participant).merge(Mailboxer::Receipt.inbox.not_trash.not_deleted)
  }
  scope :sentbox, lambda {|participant|
    participant(participant).merge(Mailboxer::Receipt.sentbox.not_trash.not_deleted)
  }
  scope :new, lambda {|participant|
    participant(participant).merge(Mailboxer::Receipt.trash)
  }
  scope :unread,  lambda {|participant|
    participant(participant).merge(Mailboxer::Receipt.is_unread)
  }
  scope :not_trash,  lambda {|participant|
    participant(participant).merge(Mailboxer::Receipt.not_trash)
  }

  #Mark the conversation as read for one of the participants
  def mark_as_read(participant)
    return unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).mark_as_read
  end

  #Mark the conversation as unread for one of the participants
  def mark_as_unread(participant)
    return unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).mark_as_unread
  end

  #Move the conversation to the trash for one of the participants
  def move_to_trash(participant)
    return unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).move_to_trash
  end

  #Takes the conversation out of the trash for one of the participants
  def untrash(participant)
    return unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).untrash
  end

  #Mark the conversation as deleted for one of the participants
  def mark_as_deleted(participant)
    return unless participant
    deleted_receipts = receipts_for(participant).mark_as_deleted
    if is_orphaned?
      destroy
    else
      deleted_receipts
    end
  end

  #Returns an array of participants
  def recipients
    return [] unless original_message
    Array original_message.recipients
  end

  #Returns an array of participants
  def participants
    recipients
  end

  #Originator of the conversation.
  def originator
    @originator ||= original_message.sender
  end

  #First message of the conversation.
  def original_message
    @original_message ||= messages.order('created_at').first
  end

  #Sender of the last message.
  def last_sender
    @last_sender ||= last_message.sender
  end

  #Last message in the conversation.
  def last_message
    @last_message ||= messages.order('created_at DESC').first
  end

  #Returns the receipts of the conversation for one participants
  def receipts_for(participant)
    Mailboxer::Receipt.conversation(self).recipient(participant)
  end

  #Returns the number of messages of the conversation
  def count_messages
    Mailboxer::Message.conversation(self).count
  end

  #Returns true if the messageable is a participant of the conversation
  def is_participant?(participant)
    return false unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).any?
  end

    #Adds a new participant to the conversation
    def add_participant(participant)
        messages.each do |message|
      Mailboxer::ReceiptBuilder.new({
        :notification => message,
        :receiver     => participant,
        :updated_at   => message.updated_at,
        :created_at   => message.created_at
      }).build.save
        end
    end

  #Returns true if the participant has at least one trashed message of the conversation
  def is_trashed?(participant)
    return false unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).new.count != 0
  end

  #Returns true if the participant has deleted the conversation
  def is_deleted?(participant)
    return false unless participant
    return receipts_for(participant).deleted.count == receipts_for(participant).count
  end

  #Returns true if both participants have deleted the conversation
  def is_orphaned?
    participants.reduce(true) do |is_orphaned, participant|
      is_orphaned && is_deleted?(participant)
    end
  end

  #Returns true if the participant has trashed all the messages of the conversation
  def is_completely_trashed?(participant)
    return false unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).new.count == receipts_for(participant).count
  end

  def is_read?(participant)
    !is_unread?(participant)
  end

  #Returns true if the participant has at least one unread message of the conversation
  def is_unread?(participant)
    return false unless participant
    receipts_for(participant).not_trash.is_unread.count != 0
  end

  # Creates a opt out object
  # because by default all particpants are opt in
  def opt_out(participant)
    return unless has_subscriber?(participant)
    opt_outs.create(:unsubscriber => participant)
  end

  # Destroys opt out object if any
  # a participant outside of the discussion is, yet, not meant to optin
  def opt_in(participant)
    opt_outs.unsubscriber(participant).destroy_all
  end

  # tells if participant is opt in
  def has_subscriber?(participant)
    !opt_outs.unsubscriber(participant).any?
  end

  protected

  #Use the default sanitize to clean the conversation subject
  def clean
    self.subject = sanitize subject
  end

  def sanitize(text)
    ::Mailboxer::Cleaner.instance.sanitize(text)
  end
end
```

Comment: The controller initializes when the rails server starts, and it may be colliding. Can you paste your model methods?

Comment: Sure, though I haven't added anything to the default mailboxer:conversations model. What would you like to see, just that model?

Comment: Just the model that creates this new scope.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you have:

```
  scope :new, lambda {|participant|
    participant(participant).merge(Mailboxer::Receipt.trash)
  }
```

Which is already defined in ActiveRecord::Base

```
Mailboxer::Conversation.new
```

exists as a class method and a scope. Changing the scope name should be enough to fix it.

As pointed in the comments, reinstall the gem will be the fastest solution.

Comment: My concern is that I didn't write this, any ideas why this would be here?

Comment: Rails generator created it is my guess. I don't know why is inheriting with active record. The mailboxer gem doesn't have any scope called new. https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/search?q=scope+%3Anew&ref=cmdform

Comment: ahh ok, I removed is and got the same error in another model. So i'm trying to re-install the gem .. and that is raising issues. I'll comment again when I'm back on track

Comment: It's the same error, just pointing me to a different file. So yes, the generator did a number on the gem files and so the simplest fix is to re-install the gem - thank you for your help

Comment: please feel free to add it as an answer and I will tick it as correct :)